# Can't SSH to a newly created "Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS" on AWS (with correct key)

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I have tried to ssh to a brand new 16.04 EC2 instance but get a "Permission denied (publickey)." I can use the same key to access a new Amazon Linux instance. It looks to me like it's a sshd issue not liking my key but I can't quite work out what I need to do to fix it (Amazon seems to only be able to create 256 bit RSA keys). Any suggestions?

```
$ ssh -Ai ~/.ssh/my-web.pem ec2-user@52.65.59.212 -vvvv                                                                                                                                                
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/ivan/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "52.65.59.212" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 52.65.59.212 [52.65.59.212] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/my-web.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ivan/.ssh/my-web.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Ubuntu-10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 52.65.59.212:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ivan/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ivan/.ssh/known_hosts:163
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 52.65.59.212
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:dECkQyAas8mb3253fWWnbKyA5sKuHZW5f+WQmZcSQEE
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ivan/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ivan/.ssh/known_hosts:163
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 52.65.59.212
debug1: Host '52.65.59.212' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ivan/.ssh/known_hosts:163
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/ivan/.ssh/my-web.pem ((nil)), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ivan/.ssh/my-web.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:pLWmaHNdQ+BtGfxIr026FfbI2d2A+MH1khcRR+3QjsQ
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu, in AWS EC2 the default user is `ubuntu`, so you have to use `ubuntu@<ip>` not `ec2-user@<ip>`.

This is the common list that you should have as a quick reference:

```
ec2-user  # (Amazon Linux, Red Hat Linux, SUSE Linux)
root      # (Red Hat Linux, SUSE Linux)
ubuntu    # (Ubuntu Linux distribution)
fedora    # (Fedora Linux distribution)
```

Reference: [How to SSH to EC2 Instance on AWS (for Beginners)](https://99robots.com/how-to-ssh-to-ec2-instance-on-aws/)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in publickey permission.

Change it to `400` with command

```
chmod 400 /home/ivan/.ssh/my-web.pem
```

Try again. Should be working.

Comment: The my-web.pem file has already had chmod run (I can connect to the Amazon Linux instances)

Comment: Before you create instance on AWS you must create key pair. That key pair you are download to your pc. That key, from AWS, must have privilege 0400 and that key is used for auth when you connect to AWS instance. You must use AWS key not your locally generated.

Comment: As stated before I am able to login into an Amazon Linux instance with that same key pair I just can't log into an Ubuntu Linux instance with the key pair. Everything else about the instances (except OS) is the same.

Comment: Try to change key on instance.